# How to use Instagram Graph API using PHP to retrieve public post info

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I need help getting started using the Graph API to retrieve basic public info from an Instagram account (account name, likes, post date, image url, description). I was able to do all of this with the Instagram API but i haven't seen any examples on how to do this using the Instagram Graph API.

Comment: Try reading the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/

Comment: thanks but thats the first thing I did

Comment: The Instagram Graphc API seems to be more about interacting with business accounts. If you’re just wanting to get details of any Instagram user, then the “traditional” API (https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) seems to be the most appropriate way.

Comment: Thanks Martin, my understanding but hopefully i'm wrong is that the standard api will stop working in july 2018

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Instagram API is going to deprecate some APIs till 2018. complete API deprecation by 2020: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/ - and everything would be moved on FB graph API.

> We will be deprecating the older Instagram API Platform in three
>   phases with complete deprecation occurring in early 2020.
>
> The following will be available until July 31, 2018:
>
> Follower List - to read the list of followers and followed-by users
>   Relationships - to follow and unfollow accounts on a user’s behalf
>   Commenting on Public Content - to post and delete comments on a user’s
>   behalf on public media The following will be available until December
>   11, 2018:
>
> Commenting - to post and delete comments on a user’s behalf on owned
>   media Public Content - to read any public profile info and media on a
>   user’s behalf Likes - to like and unlike media on a user’s behalf
>   Subscriptions - to receive notifications when media is posted The
>   following will be available until early 2020:
>
> Basic - to read a user’s profile info and media

But yes, your concern is correct - there is no way for public content in graph api.

And your use case to search on public content won't be supported.

FB wants to move to business account approach rather being a photo repository for search (like twitter or pinterest or flickr). they would want to have brand accounts with ads and other account type specific features. (like fb or wechat)